# SQL query with CASE statement ,multiple variables and sub variables

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

i am working on dataset where i need to write an query for below requirement either in `R-programming`    or `SQLDF` , i want to know and learn to write in both language ( `SQL and R` ) ,kindly help.

Requirement is  : i need to print Variable "a" from table when 
  Total_Scores of `id` 34 and `Rank` 3 is GREATER THAN `Total_Scores` of `id` 34 and Rank     4 else Print Variable b . 
  This above case Applicable for each `id` and `Rank`

```
id   Rank    Variable     Total_Scores
34      3     a              11
34      4     b               6
126     3     c              15
126     4     d              18
190     3     e               9
190     4     f              10
388     3     g              20
388     4     h              15
401     3     i              15
401     4     x              11
476     3     y              11
476     4     z              11
536     3     p              15
536     4     q               6
```

i have tried to write `SQL CASE` statement and i am stuck ,could you please 
help to write the query

```
"select id ,Rank ,
                      CASE 
           WHEN (select Total_Scores from table where id == 34 and Rank == 3) > (select Total_Scores from table where id == 34 and Rank == 4)
           THEN "Variable is  )
```

Final output Should be :

```
id   Rank    Variable     Total_Scores
34      3        a          11
126     4        d          18
190     4        f          10
388     3        g          20
401     3        i          15
536     3        p          15
```

Comment: id 476 does not appear in the sample output. Is that an error?

Comment: My apologies, it should be there ,in final output.

Comment: What should be there -- both rows or one of the rows or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Requirement is to select the rows having highest Total_scores for each id,and at this I need rows if Total_Scores Level

Comment: This is still not clear. Do you need *all* such rows for a particular id or just *any one* of those rows?  Both alternatives are common requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want the row with the highest score for each id.  A canonical way to write this in SQL uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by score desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This returns one row per `id`, even when the scores are tied.  If you want all rows in that case, use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

An alternative method can have better performance with an index on `(id, score)`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.score = (select max(t2.score) from t t2 where t2.id = t.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
SELECT T.* FROM (
    SELECT id, 
        MAX(Total_Scores) Max_Total_Scores 
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING MAX(Total_Scores) > MIN(Total_Scores) ) AS MX 
INNER JOIN MyTable T ON MX.id = T.id AND MX.Max_Total_Scores = T.Total_Scores
ORDER BY id
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80f3f9/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

In R

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
         filter(Total_Scores == max(Total_Scores)) %>% filter(n()==1) %>% 
         ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 4
   id  Rank Variable Total_Scores
 <int> <int> <chr>           <int>
1    34     3 a                  11
2   126     4 d                  18
3   190     4 f                  10
4   388     3 g                  20
5   401     3 i                  15
6   536     3 p                  15
```

**Data**

```
df <- read.table(text="
             id   Rank    Variable     Total_Scores
               34      3     a              11
               34      4     b               6
               126     3     c              15
               126     4     d              18
               190     3     e               9
               190     4     f              10
               388     3     g              20
               388     4     h              15
               401     3     i              15
               401     4     x              11
               476     3     y              11
               476     4     z              11
               536     3     p              15
               536     4     q               6 

               ",header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: Thank you Suliman . However i am able to figure it out the solution  data %>% 
       group_by(id) %>% 
       mutate(Rank = rank(Total_Scores))%>%
       filter(Rank == 2)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that what you want is to get the subset of rows whose `Total_Scores` is largest for that `id` here are two approaches.

The question did not discuss how to deal with ties.  There is one `id` in the example that has a tie but there is no output corresponding to it which I assume was not intendedand that either both the rows should have been output or one of them. Anyways in the solutions below in (1) it will give one of the rows arbitrarily if there are duplicates whereas (2) will give both.

**1) sqldf**

If you use `max` in an SQLite `select` it will automatically select the other variables of the same row so:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select id, Rank, Variable, max(Total_Scores) Total_Scores 
       from DF
       group by id")
```

giving:

```
       id Rank Variable Total_Scores
1  34    3        a           11
2 126    4        d           18
3 190    4        f           10
4 388    3        g           20
5 401    3        i           15
6 476    3        y           11
7 536    3        p           15
```

**2) base R**  In base R we can use `ave` and `subset` like this:

```
subset(DF, ave(Total_Scores, id, FUN = function(x) x == max(x)) > 0)
```

giving:

```
    id Rank Variable Total_Scores
1   34    3        a           11
4  126    4        d           18
6  190    4        f           10
7  388    3        g           20
9  401    3        i           15
11 476    3        y           11
12 476    4        z           11
13 536    3        p           15
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
Lines <- "id   Rank    Variable     Total_Scores
34      3     a              11
34      4     b               6
126     3     c              15
126     4     d              18
190     3     e               9
190     4     f              10
388     3     g              20
388     4     h              15
401     3     i              15
401     4     x              11
476     3     y              11
476     4     z              11
536     3     p              15
536     4     q               6"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```